# Selecting a machine learning training method

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, encog

I have the following data which has already been normalized:

- customer id
- customer age
- customer location
- home owner
- car vale
- risk factor
- married
- package a
- package b
- package c

Based on all the factors above, I would like to predict what packages; either A, B or C, a customer is likely to purchase.

However, I am sort of lost in a sea of options.  There are many training methodologies such as Linear perceptron, genetic algorithm, time series forecasting, auto-associative networks, and many more.

How do I know which one is likely to work best for solving this type of problem where there is more than one output?

**Edit:**

My question is based on the assumption that there is an optimal strategy for this particular scenario because I understand that certain algorithms are used more often in certain scenarios, such as genetic algorithms are used often in handwriting recognition programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'd recommend looking up the [no free lunch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem).  Effectively, you can't trivially identify the "best classifier" for a problem.  Personally, I would use scikit-learn and test out a bunch of classifiers with proper training, testing, and cross-validation sets and see what the best result looks like.

Also, it depends on your case.  Can users purchase multiple packages or no?

Comment: I see; well I am not using python, I am using C#/Encog.  Are you suggesting that I implement a number of different strategies (which you call classifiers) like perceptron, genetic algorithm, etc?

Comment: And, yes, users can purchase multiple packages.

Comment: Im suggesting you find implementations of these algorithms.

Comment: I have gone through a number of simple Iris data examples (very popular machine learning problem) and I've seen the traveling salesman problem, too.  However, this problem is different from those because the number of outputs is 3, not just one, as was the case of the Iris dataset.  Any recommendations for such a problem?

Comment: If your answer is "I don't know," that's ok.  Just let me know your opinion please.

Comment: I recommend trying things.  Every algorithm had a way to solve it in a multi-class classification problem.  This is not similar to the traveling salesperson problem in any way.  I'd recommend phrasing the problem as three binary classification problems.

Comment: Just struggling how to phrase it as three binary classifications problems.  Not sure how to get from A to B.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Train a classifier to determine whether or not the person will purchase package A, then train a classifier to determine whether or not the person will purchase package B, then train a classifier to determine whether or not the person will purchase package C.  Its that easy.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  Thanks.